# ASP.NET Container-Specific Master Pages for Safari or Chrome

Tags: asp.net, browser, safari, google-chrome, master-pages

Has anyone been able to create **Container-Specific Master Pages** for Safari or Chrome?

I can't find any ".browser" files for either of these.

How often is the %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\CONFIG\Browsers directory  updated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for .browser files, try:

http://owenbrady.net/browsercaps/

specifically, what you're looking for can be found here:

http://owenbrady.net/browsercaps/OceanAppleWebKit.browser.xml